# Soft Shadow while preserving IES light pattern

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

i am making a interior scene where i have downlight right above a window frame and i want the shadow casted below to be soft but i also want to preserve the IES profile detail since increasing the point light size blurs the IES light

[image: light in my render]

[image: Results i am looking for]

i want the light to look like a point light with a size 0 but cast a soft shadow is there any work arounds to this other than increasing the size